# DOMException: String contains an invalid character

Tags: javascript, angular5

When I add [(ngModel)] in code I get this error:

> DOMException: String contains an invalid character

The component file:

```
const keyInput = document.createElement('input');
keyInput.setAttribute('class', 'form-control input-transparent');
keyInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
keyInput.setAttribute('[(ngModel)]', trans.key);
keyInput.setAttribute('name', 'keys[]');
keyInput.setAttribute('value', trans.key);
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to create dynamic form?

Comment: Yes and i also want to get these values after submit form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use Dynamic form feature already available in Angular. It provides a lot of control on form controls as well as a systematic approach too. Please [follow the link](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form), for more details

Answer (score 3):

in my case I have fount the typo in my template like this: `<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="errorTimeNotAvailable"
                 jhiTranslate="businesslogic.create.kindergartenclass.timenotavailable" [translateValues]="{ entityName: this.concurrentExisitngKindergartenClass }" ]>` with extra **]**

everything compiled well, but failed at the runtime